# serve protected images in a django template through nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-templates, django-views

I am using nginx to serve static and media django files and apache as a reverse proxy.
the media files are protected.
I am able to acess the media images from a django view using this code:

```
response['X-Accel-Redirect']='/media/%s'% obj.photo
```

but i want to display protected image in a template. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please help me  with this